# Lectures on differential forms and Riemannian Geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, book-recommendation

I've just taken an introductory course on Riemannian Geometry. I've read several chapters of Do Carmo's book Riemannian Geometry and O'Neill's one on Semi-Riemannian Geometry. Also, I am familiarized with the theory of Differentiable Manifolds (I've read the classical books of Warner, Postnikov, Kumaresan, Boothby...), Lie groups and algebras and Algebraic Topology. I am wondering if does anyone know any lectures or books developing the theory of Riemannian (or Semi-Riemannian) geometry in terms of differential forms. I know the classical lectures by Élie Cartan on the moving frame's method (repere mobile) and the Differential Geometry books of M. Spivak are quite good references.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look for lecture notes by Robert Bryant.

Comment: Dieudonne's *Treatise on Analysis Vol IV* treats principal connections and Riemannian geometry, eventually getting to the 'standard' stuff as covered in Do Carmo, but for some reason I liked Dieudonne's presentation better (more systematic and detailed), and there are lot's of interesting exercises as well (though long). He uses differential forms consistently throughout. Having said this, he does reference previous volumes (mainly Vol III which is about smooth manifolds, vector bundles, and connections on vector bundles).

Comment: Chern/Chen/Lam *Lectures on Differential Geometry*. Also look for books by Bryant's various students: Clelland, Landsberg and Ivey.

Comment: Also: Sharpe's GTM 166: *Differential Geometry: Cartan's Generalization of Klein's Erlangen Program*. I find it difficult to read unless one already knows what's going on, however.

Comment: @TedShifrin found the Chern lectures you talked about pretty nice. Thanks!